# Running Total By Date in Visualization

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a line chart visualization that shows a constantly increasing sum over time.  I think this would be called a cumulative total or a running total, but most of the questions I've seen on here have been about showing a total at the bottom of a matrix, subtotals, etc.  Instead, I just want to visualize the units from the previous date being added to the current date, and so on.  Not sure if this would be a custom column in the dataset or if there is an existing function for this.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto **Quick Measures**, in the "Calculation" dropdown, select "Totals - **Running Total**", pull in **Base Value** (what you want to aggregate) and **Field** (probably your calender) and here you are!